# Iterating Subset of Indices Efficiency

Tags: python, performance, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through a subset of elements in a list based on another list of indices.

The shortest / most pythonic way seems like it would use list comprehension to the effect of:

```
    for elt in [lst[idx] for idx in idxs]:
        elt.do_stuff()
        elt.do_more_stuff()
```

But I can't shake the feeling that if I'm going to be looping this a lot, rebuilding the list comprehension every time might be expensive and I should spend the extra line to just write:

```
    for idx in indxs:
        elt = lst[idx]
        elt.do_stuff()
        elt.do_more_stuff()
```

Can someone who knows more about python and its relative efficiencies / inefficiencies way in on the actual computational cost difference between these approaches? I know, I know both ways could probably work fine, but once I started wondering about the difference it got me curious.

Comment: The second one will be as efficient as anything else you might get as a suggestion

Comment: @smac89: Agreed. I offered options, but I'd default to the second solution and only consider a switch if profiling showed it was the key chokepoint and one of my other solutions actually showed an improvement (unlikely to be a major improvement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second loop is fine, but your first loop can be made to work without building a temporary `list` by just using [a generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression):

```
for elt in (lst[idx] for idx in idxs):
    elt.do_stuff()
    elt.do_more_stuff()
```

or (probably slightly faster if there are a lot of indices) by (ab?)using `map`:

```
for elt in map(lst.__getitem__, idxs):
    elt.do_stuff()
    elt.do_more_stuff()
```

In both cases (at least on Py3 where `map` returns an iterator, not a new `list`), the effect is to lazily look up each index as the next `elt` is requested; it's not eagerly making a `list` before the loop even begins.

There is one other option that you might consider if you're going to be looking up the same set of indices repeatedly (that is, `idxs` doesn't change). You could create an `operator.itemgetter` once up front, and use that. It would operate eagerly (like the `list` comprehension), but it would:

1. Return a `tuple` instead of a `list` (slightly more memory efficient and with better memory locality, but usually not a meaningful difference)
2. Push the building of said `tuple`, start to finish, down to the C layer, where a `list` comprehension, while using specialized bytecodes, still has to do all of its work in the regular interpreter, which at least on CPython is slower than most work pushed to C

For that approach, you'd do:

```
# Done once up front
from operator import itemgetter
getidxs = itemgetter(*idxs)  # Note: Will fail if idxs is not at least length 2; won't return tuple when getting one item

# Done every time
for elt in getidxs(lst):
    elt.do_stuff()
    elt.do_more_stuff()
```

You'd need to profile to determine:

1. Whether any of this optimization is actually needed
2. Which solution makes the most sense for you (eager solutions like `itemgetter` and the listcomp use more memory, but might run faster; lazy solutions have fixed and small memory overhead, but might run a titch slower)